# I got error while run cron job using php, How to i fixed it?

Tags: php, cron

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/file.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/file.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `0'
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/file.php: line 2: `set_time_limit(0);'
```

the above error, i got while run cron,

- how to fixed that?
- and the path from document root
- shall i give virtual path for that, like http://domain.com/file.php, and also am try this, but it  ll return the error "Non such file directory"...

can anyone help me... Thanks in Advance..

Regards,
Vinoth S

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT is not defined while runing cron jobs.

Comment: you should include your full script including your crontab setting, to me, it seems that you are using wrong PHP binary for executing the cronjob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank u for all ur comments... its very useful to me... But i try the all the way, But my hosting domain ll not support, thats y i tried,

```
                          php -q /path/to/the/script.php
```

like that,  its working fine,My cron now working fine... Thank u all...

Regards,
Vinoth S

Answer (score 8):

You're directly invoking the .php file. The shell looks for a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and finds `<?php` which is not a valid command line interpreter.

You'll have to prefix your script with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
```

Or in your crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /path/to/the/script.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `#!/usr/bin/php5` to the top of your script as in [goreSplatter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633739/i-got-error-while-run-cron-job-using-php-how-to-i-fixed-it/4633801#4633801) perfect for scripts your are writing to run on a single machine. If you want to ensure that the script will work on other machines that might have PHP installed elsewhere (such as `/usr/local/bin/php5`), then you can make use of the `env` command to search for php under the current user's $PATH:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Comment: It is true, `env` might be someplace else, but I believe that its location is pretty consistent across at least Linux distributions and maybe other UNIX/UNIX-like operating systems. The issue with addressing php directly is that both installation via package management systems (RPM, apt, etc) to `/usr/bin` and custom compiling to `/usr/local/bin` are very common.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code for the cron set up. Also in your cpanel set an email id where you can get an email whenever cron execute successfully so that you know that you have successfully set a cron job.

wget -O -  http://YOURSITE/cron.php?cron_key=abcd